# Инсталлятор для приложения

Tags: c++builder, windows

Уважаемые пользователи форума. Помогите, пожалуйста, подскажите при помощи какой программы можно создать инсталлятор для приложения на языке C++ Builder.

Answer (score 2):

Рискну добавить к ответу уважаемого [[@Asen](/users/5040/asen)](/users/5040/asen) следующее. Инсталляторов - дофига и простых, и сложных. Однако, прежде чем воспользоваться одним из них (для программы на C Builder!), необходимо понять, каков должен быть состав пакета. А он (состав) различен для программы в форме Stand Alone (большой размер ехе-шника, "все включено") и для ехе-шника, который устанавливается на комп, где программы C Builder уже устанавливались совместно с RunTime-библиотеками и пакетами. Чтобы выяснить состав инсталляционного пакета необходимо после линковки запустить через командную строку: **tdump.exe MyProg.exe->file.txt**. И, затем, в текстовом файле в разделах Import найти то, что необходимо включить в пакет.
Удачи!

Comment: Dependency Walker же!

Comment: Не понял Вашего восклицания, уважаемый @karmadro4, если, конечно, оно относится ко мне.

Comment: @BuilderC, [всё очень просто](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Walker).

Comment: tdump.exe входит в дистрибутив. Почему бы не воспользоваться "родным" продуктом?

Comment: Потому что трубодамп ни разу не предназначен для рекурсивного обхода таблиц импорта.

Answer (score 1):

Инсталлятор для средств разработки под C++ не нужен, для Windows - это Visual C++. Там все включено. Для приложений - либо проект Setup в Visual Studio, либо проект [WiX](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) для всего остального, либо инструменты третьих сторон (InstallShield и т.п.).

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял, вы имеете ввиду создание инсталляционного пакета с расширением .exe для последующего запуска и установки приложения. Есть очень удобный `install pocket maker` - 
[Smart Install Maker](http://ru.sminstall.com/download.html).

Comment: не помогает требует .dll файл

Comment: Это уже вопрос не ко мне =)

Answer (score 1):

Я использовал I**nstallShield** - работает прекрасно, и все ссылки подтягивает "за раз".

Comment: для C++ Builder 6.0

Comment: У меня, к сожалению, нет InstallShield Express :-( 

А хотелось бы!